# Unzipping a .jar archive file without writing to disk

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I would like to start a java application from a password protected archive.

I've an executable jar, and I'm able to run it by double clicking in a JRE working environment. Also `java -jar runnable.jar` works.
What I would like to achieve is making this archive password protected and launching it with the help of another executable without extracting the content of the archive. Something like `launcher.exe runnable.jar -p ArchiveP@ssword123`

As we know `java -jar runnable.jar` command loads the jar into jre environment. I would like to do the same for the password protected `runnable_Protected.jar`. I think it can be achieved by extracting the archive into a path with the help of `jar` command or any other utility like `7z`. What I would like to achieve is loading the jar into the memory/jre only. (My code is already obfuscated, this question is not related to that)

Any suggestion ?

Comment: As .jar files are basically just zip archives, maybe `ZipFile` can help you

Comment: My first thought is to write a custom `ClassLoader` that decrypts the class files on-the-fly, but I'm not sure if that will work with your use case.

Comment: @byJavaDev it's already obvious in the question jar is an archive. `java -jar yourRunnable.jar -p pass` has no `pass` option to unzip and load the app to jre. I'm looking a workaround for it.

Comment: Why not do: `java -jar runnable.jar` "Please enter correct password or this app will exit:"

Comment: @g00se the purpose is not protecting the use of app, the purpose is not letting decompile of the jars in the archive. An extra level of protection for the source code (it's already obfuscated).